# Display background form inline

Tags: html, css

I want to make, that show my backgrounds forms in row, I try this:

```
        <div id="items">
        <div id="item_bg"></div>
        <div id="item_bg"></div>
        <div id="item_bg"></div>
        </div>

        #items {
        display: block;
        width: 700px;
        }
        #item_bg {
        background: black;
        border-radius: 7px;
        height: 128px;
        width: 128px;
        }
```

Now it looks like this: https://jsfiddle.net/vmz76s1z/
But I want that show in row

Answer (score 3):

Add either `float:left` or `display: inline-block` to your child elements. Note that IDs **must** be unique, so change `#item_bg` to a class.

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/vmz76s1z/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

First an id should be unique in the HTML page.

So first you have to change `id="item_bg"` to `class="item_bg"`
Then you have two solutions :

First if you want to stay in an inherit positioning, you can do :

```
 .item_bg {
            background: black;
            display:inline-block;
            border-radius: 7px;
            height: 128px;
            width: 128px;
            }
```

secondly if you want a relative floating item and choose the side to align :

```
 .item_bg {
            background: black;
            float:left;
            border-radius: 7px;
            height: 128px;
            width: 128px;
            }
```

Comment: This would pretty much be my solution too except @j08691 is right,  IDs must be unique so change it to class="item_bg" then in CSS change to .item_bg

Comment: yes you're right id should be change by class to be correct.